# How to inject/evaluate javascript in mobile safari during XCUITest automation?

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, xctest, xcuitest

I am testing in mobile safari using XCTest framework. I want to inject/evaluate some javascript. Is it possible to do ? If yes, how ?

I am trying to automate in Mobile safari. I have some javascripts. I will evaluate them to get required  object details based on some input parameters. Before evaluating I need to inject javascripts.

I read about ActionExtensions, Can I use it for this purpose ?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are you working on (forms, input fields etc) and what should your JS do? 
And afaik, its not possible, but let's see after you share your use case.